# Como converter Object para byte[] e o inverso?

Tags: java

Preciso enviar um arquivo por uma conexão udp para um trabalho da faculdade. Criei uma classe pacote que contém o cabeçalho e parte do arquivo a ser enviado. Fiz o seguinte método para converter o objeto para byte[]:

```
 public static byte[] objectToByte(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

}
```

E criei o seguinte para converter de volta para Object:

```
public static Object byteToObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
    Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();
    return object;
}
```

Testei e os métodos sem enviar pela conexão e funcionaram, mas quando envio pelo datagrama e vai ser feito a conversão de volta para Object dá o erro:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00 
Justamente nessa linha:

```
Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

método da Classe Cliente que começa o envio de pacotes:

```
public void executa(String host, int porta, String arquivo) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        this.porta = porta;
        this.caminho = arquivo;
        this.host=host;           
        //Fazendo HandShake
        Pacote pct = new Pacote(nSeq,ack,(short)2);
        DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(Manipulador.objectToByte(pct), 12, addr, porta);
        client = new DatagramSocket();
        //primeira msg
        client.send(envio);
```

O primeiro pacote é enviado e então o erro acontece quando ele chega ao servidor, na thread que recebe os pacotes:

```
public void run() {
    for (DatagramPacket pkg : servidor.getPacotes()) {
        try {

            Pacote pct = (Pacote) Manipulador.converterParaObject(pkg.getData());
            int flag = pct.getFlag();
```

Na hora de converter os bytes recebidos para o objeto Pacote. Eu havia colocado um println após o recebimento da resposta do servidor que nunca é executado, por isso percebi que o erro acontece no primeiro envio.

Comment: Dando uma pesquisada, isso parece ser problema com serialização e não necessariamente a forma como você está fazendo a conversão. Alguma classe do seu projeto implementa a interface `Serializable`?

Comment: Sim, a classe pacote, que é o objeto que eu envio através da conexão udp.

Comment: Ela só implementa Serializable e nada mais? Se sim, nem precisa postar. Além disso, poste a classe que envia via udp.

Comment: Só implementa serializable.

Answer (score 0):

**tive este mesmo problema e resolvi da seguinte forma**

```
   Object ObjetoExemplo = new object(); *// este objeto é só um exemplo*
   byte[] EXAMPLE_DATA = gson.toJson(ObjetoExemplo).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

lembre-se de usar a biblioteca do google **Gson**